# How to show Blender thumbnails in Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: file-browser

I have installed the 2.8 version of blender through steam Ubuntu. Location in `/home/myusername/games/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Blender`. I can not understand where to copy `blender-thumbnailer.py`.

What's the "PATH" directory? In General I have a lot of projects associated with the work and with no preview I can find something).

---

*Asking on behalf of a user who emailed me.*

Answer (score 4):

Save this file to: `$HOME/.local/share/thumbnailers/blender.thumbnailer`

```
[Thumbnailer Entry]
TryExec=blender-thumbnailer
Exec=blender-thumbnailer %i %o
MimeType=application/x-blender;
```

---

If you install Blender via Ubuntu's package manager, `blender-thumbnailer` will be in your `PATH`, otherwise you'll need to add it.

From what I can tell, you need to have `blender-thumbnailer` in your `PATH` for this to work.

See: [How can I edit the $PATH on linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/488173/how-can-i-edit-the-path-on-linux#488175)

---

Note, it would be good to see if this could be simplified or even done automatically.

Comment: I would add to this answer that `PATH` is an environment variable that stores paths that Linux uses to search for programs. It can be viewed by typing `$PATH` on the terminal. Not sure if it's a good idea though to advise a user to edit `/etc/environment`, `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` when they don't know what `PATH` is. Could go wrong.